# Induced homomorphism, first isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone explain to me what an induced homomorphism is? This is pertaining to the first isomorphism theorem in abstract algebra.

If we have a function $f$ that maps group $G$ to $\operatorname{im}(f)$ in $H$, then the function $\bar{f}$ maps quotient group $G/K$ to $\operatorname{im}(f)$ and the left coset $gK$ maps to $f(g)$. This is the induced homomorphism.

I don't quite understand what this all means.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no formal definition of "induced" in this context - the word is merely descriptive, and indicates that the definition of $\bar{f}$ is entirely derived from that of $f$.

The situation you have is that there is a homomorphism $f\colon G\to H$, with kernel $K$. Now you can define a map $\bar{f}\colon G/K\to H$ by $gK\mapsto f(g)$; this is well-defined (i.e. if $gK=hK$ then $f(g)=f(h)$) precisely because $K$ is the kernel of $f$, as you should check.

The homomorphism $\bar{f}$ is said to be induced from $f$ because, roughly speaking, it has "the same" definition as $f$ - only the domain has changed in an interesting way.

There are other situations in which you might use the word "induced". For example, if you have a map $f\colon X\to Y$ and $Y\subset Z$, then you could obtain a function $\bar{f}\colon X\to Z$ "induced from $f$" by composing $f$ with the inclusion $Y\to Z$. Or you could get $\widetilde{f}\colon X\times X\to Y\times Y$ by $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto(f(x_1),f(x_2))$, which could also be said to be "induced from $f$".